# jQuery .each to get post meta and subtract from a sum

Tags: php, jquery

I have a custom post type that uses a custom meta box to output numbers (of travelers) and am using jQuery to deduct those numbers from 20 (because that’s how many people can go on the tour) to output a final number of availability. This works fine per-page, but not if I’m outputting *all* of the tours. I can’t seem to get `.each` to work; it finds the first existence of these numbers and applies it to all of them.

Here’s the php query I’m using to get the post types and the content from each post of that type:

```
<ul id="tourNav">

    <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => array( 'wpr_item' ), 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'   => 'ASC', ) );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        echo '<li>';

        echo '<div>';
        echo '<span class="num1">';
        echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tour_details_number', true );
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<span class="num2">';
        echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tour_details_number2', true );
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<span class="num3">';
        echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tour_details_number3', true );
        echo '</span></div>';

        echo '<a href="/reserve-items/?add-reserve=';
        echo the_id();
        echo '">';
        echo the_title();
        echo '</a>';
        echo ' <span class="count"></span></li>';

    endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Which, of course outputs all posts of that type. However, for each list item, I need to do the math, granted those numbers exist in each (i.e. the post meta such as `tour_details_number`).

Here’s my script thus far, that should work with this output information:

```
$('#tourNav li').each(function(){
var maximum = 20;
var deduct1 = $('.num1').text();
var deduct2 = $('.num2').text();
var deduct3 = $('.num3').text();
var slot = maximum - deduct1 - deduct2 - deduct3;
$('.count').html(slot);
});
```

Here’s [a live view](http://bibletourslacma.com/tour/) where you can see my problem (please go to the bottom of the page where the blue links appear). Next to each list item should appear either the number 20 (the maximum) or a lesser number as a result of the post meta(s) being present to do the subtraction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery for something like this, it would be better done if you just use php!

So if you store those 3 values in variables you can then do basic math with that data about output the results.

```
while ($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();

    $tourNum1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_details_number', true);
    $tourNum2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_details_number2', true);
    $tourNum3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_details_number3', true);
    $total = 20 - ($tourNum1 + $tourNum2 + $tourNum3);

    echo '<li>';

    echo '<div>';
    echo '<span class="num1">';
    echo $tourNum1;
    echo '</span>';
    echo '<span class="num2">';
    echo $tourNum2;
    echo '</span>';
    echo '<span class="num3">';
    echo $tourNum3;
    echo '</span></div>';

    echo '<a href="/reserve-items/?add-reserve=';
    echo the_id();
    echo '">';
    echo the_title();
    echo '</a>';
    echo " <span class='count'>".$total."</span></li>";
endwhile;
```

Comment: I thought this might be a better route, but your code was the key. When future generations speak of awesome, you sir, shall be mentioned at length. Thanks so much @Nath